# SQL Server function to parse docket numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

On our database in a Cases table, the Docket field stores the docket number(s) for each case.  Each docket number takes the form such as

- AB19-1-000
- CD19-1043-000
- EF18-24-001

These are comprised of "root" dockets and "sub" dockets.  The roots here are

- AB19-1
- CD19-1043
- EF18-24

The root dockets are comprised of the two alpha character docket prefix, which indicates the case type.  Followed by a two numerical character code indicating the fiscal year the case was filed.  Then a hyphen.  Then a "sequence" number (with no fixed # of digits, although none have ever had more than 4 digits) indicating the sequence that the case was filed (relative to other cases of the same type that were filed in that fiscal year).

The final three digits (after the final hyphen) of the overall docket number represent the "subdocket," and are to allow for multiple filings within the docket.  The initial filing is always docketed with a 000 subdocket.  Subsequent filings within that root docket are subdocketed as 001, 002, 003, etc.

To make things more complicated, there can be multiple docket numbers listed within the Docket field, and (in the horrid legacy database design we have) multiple docket numbers are always separated with exactly one space.  (I know.  Don't get me started.)

I want to create a tool that will help us generate the docket number for new cases easier/quicker than our current approach (which uses a VBA loop and is very slow).  Specifically, I want to write a function for use on SQL Server that will spit out the next sequence number for a new filing of a given type and fiscal year.

The steps would be roughly:

1. Accept as an argument a two character case type and a two digit fiscal year.
2. Identify all docket numbers entered where the alpha prefix is the specified case type and the next two characters are the specified fiscal year (ignoring subdocket, which we don't care about here).
3. Identify the highest existing sequence number for that case type and docket year.
4. Add one to the identified number, and return that number.

I'm a decent programmer, but my SQL is pretty limited to fairly normal queries.  I have very limited experience creating functions.  So any help (even a general outline of what this kind of function might looks like and how to create it) is much appreciated.

Here's some code to generate some simple test data.

```
CREATE TABLE MyCases (
    CaseId   INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
    Docket   VARCHAR(50) not null
);

INSERT INTO MyCases 
VALUES 
(1, 'XL14-204-001 TS14-1-000 PI14-1-000'),
(2, 'PI14-2-000'),
(3, 'PI14-3-000'),
(4, 'PI14-4-001 XL14-22-000'),
(5, 'PI14-6-000'),
(6, 'PI14-7-000 XL14-382-000'),
(7, 'PI15-1-000 XL15-23-000'),
(8, 'PI15-2-000 TS15-23-000'),
(9, 'PI15-3-000'),
(10, 'PI15-4-000 TS15-2-000')
;
```

And with the desired function, if the user entered MyFunction('PI',14), the result would be 8, because the highest existing sequential number for all PI14 docket numbers is PI14-7, and adding one to 7 gives 8.  Similarly, the result for MyFunction('PI',15) would be 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create or alter function MyFunction(@RootDocket char(2), @FiscalYear smallint)
returns int as
begin
    declare @NextSequenceNumber int;

    with q as
    (
    select 
        c.CaseId, 
        cd.Docket,
        RootDocket = left(cd.Docket,2),
        FiscalYear = cast(right(left(cd.docket,4),2) as tinyint),
        SequenceNumber = cast(substring(cd.Docket,6, charindex('-',cd.Docket,7)-6) as smallint),
        SubDocket = cast(right(cd.Docket,3) as smallint)
    from dbo.mycases c
    cross apply (select value Docket from string_split(Docket,' ') ) cd(Docket)
    )
    select @NextSequenceNumber = max(SequenceNumber) + 1
    from q 
    where RootDocket = @RootDocket
      and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear

    return @NextSequenceNumber;
end
go 

select dbo.MyFunction('PI',15);
select dbo.MyFunction('PI',14);
```

outputs

```
-----------
5



-----------
8
```

Comment: OK this is a better solution than mine because: 1) it avoids the need for a loop 2) it pulls out the highest value, not the first available gap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses a loop to sequentially check each possible sequence number for the given case type and year. As soon as an available sequence number is found, it is returned.

This might be a little more optimized that what you requested, in the sense that it will fill the gaps in the sequence, if there are any. This might, or might not be what you need.

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNextAvailableSequence (
    @case_type VARCHAR(2), 
    @fiscal_year INT 
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @seq INT;
    DECLARE @done INT;
    SET @done = 0;
    SET @seq = 0;

    WHILE @done = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @seq = @seq + 1;
        IF (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM MyCases 
            WHERE ' ' + docket LIKE 
                '% ' 
                + @case_type
                + CAST(@fiscal_year as VARCHAR(2)) 
                + '-' 
                + CAST(@seq as VARCHAR(2)) 
                + '%'
        ) = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @done = 1;
       END;
    END;

    RETURN @seq;

END;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06533c3ebce763a9700e873e876ad1ec)**:

```
SELECT dbo.GetNextAvailableSequence('PI', 14);
```

```
| (No column name) |
| ---------------: |
|                5 |
```

This fills the first gap for `PI-14`.

```
select dbo.GetNextAvailableSequence('PI', 15);
```

```
| (No column name) |
| ---------------: |
|                5 |
```

There are no gaps for `PI-15`, this is the first available sequence.